# How to display only one item with a nested form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I'm editing a nested form (with cocon) in Rails 6. I have a reference model that can manage multiple nested vintages.

I can create my nest form with reference and vintages children with success. However, for my needs, in this form, I want to only display one nested child.

```
<%= form_with model: @reference, url: "update", :method => "post" do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :vintages do |vintages_form| %>
    <% if vintages_form.object.year.to_i == @vintage.year %>
      .. display form
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

At the time, the only way to display the nested vintage object I want is to write:

```
<% if vintages_form.object.year.to_i == @vintage.year %>
```

It works but when I update the form, Rails has created multiple empty children:

```
"vintages_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"year"=>"2014", "price"=>"23.79"}, "id"=>"3"},
     "1"=>{"id"=>"2"},
     "2"=>{"id"=>"1"}}},
```

How to remove them in the form ?
Is there a good way to only display the wanted vintage directly ?

Note that my SQL code is already querying the @reference with only the right vintage... but Rails display all vintages for the references by default.

Of course, I need my @reference to have "many" vintages (has_many), but for this form I want only 1 vintage as a nested attribute.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain the relation between reference and vintage? I guess here you want to update the `vintage` while updating the `reference`. And could you post the controller code for the edit action please

Comment: Hello Clara. 1 reference has_many vintages. And true, as I wrote, I want to only display and edit 1 nested vintage (chosen) in the form, even if there are multiple in the db. The problem is Rails displays all nested vintages by default.

Comment: Ok, yeah, thats the normal behaviour for the nested form I guess, to display all associated records. I don't know the use case for your app, but it seems to me like your DB structure might not be set up idealy? If a reference has many vintage, why do you only want to update one? And why in a nested form? 
If you want to keep your approach, you can always clean up the params in the update action.

Comment: Yes, it's a special use case to verify/validate each vintage associated to each parent reference. I also have another nested object, an image, for the vintage. As I can't validate all vintages and images in 1 form, I want to validate vintage after vintage. I will clean up what is required in the params. Thanks. Alexandre